# Use COPY but table has extra columns?

Tags: postgresql

I've got a CSV file from a vendor. I want to COPY it into a table, except the table has a couple extra columns I want populate via derivation in a trigger. Fairly straight forward copy: `copy mytable from '/some/file.csv' DELIMITER ',' csv;`

The copy command fails telling me there's missing data:
`ERROR:  missing data for column "arrival_dates"`

Well, of course, that column isn't in the original csv. Is there a way to force copy to just fill in the columns it is getting? Essentially, the csv has the first 18 columns, then there are two more I'm deriving and populating via trigger. I've tried assigning a DEFAULT to the columns in the table declaration, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's fairly trivial. Like `INSERT`, `COPY` allows you to specify the columns that the fields of the input field correspond to.

If your table has `col1`, `col2`, `col3` and `col4`, but the file does not contain the third column, you can simply

```
COPY atable(col1, col2, col4)
FROM '/some/file.csv'
   (FORMAT 'csv', DELIMITER ',');
```

Comment: this works with both `COPY` and also `\copy` in psql

Comment: So, if the csv had 3 columns `a,b,c` and my table has 4 `a,b,c,d` I can do `COPY (a,b,c) FROM 'some/file.cxv'` and it'll stop complaining about the missing d column?

Comment: Yes. You can verify it yourself.